# Retrieve data from cookies and display in next page

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am new to JavaScript. I have created the login page and i know how to save data in cookies now i want to know how to retrieve the data from cookie when i click on login button and display in next page. I tried but i am unable to get the solution. Can anyone help me to resolve this problem.

I have added the code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Login Page</title>
 </head>
   <body>
    <script>
     var myCookies = {};
     
     function saveCookies()
     {
      myCookies["_mail"] = document.getElementById("mail").value;
       document.cookie="";
    var expiresAttrib = new Date(Date.now()+60*1000).toString();
    var cookieString = "";
    for(var key in myCookies)
    {
      cookieString = key+"="+myCookies[key]+";"+expiresAttrib+";";
      document.cookie = cookieString;
    }
      document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = document.cookie;
    }  
    </script>
     <div class="container">
     <h1>LOGIN FORM<h1>
    <p><input type="email" id="mail" placeholder="Enter Email" name="uname" required></p>
    <p><input type="password"  id="Pass" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required></p>

    <button id="btnLogin" class="login" onclick="saveCookies()" >Login</button> 
    <p id="abc">
    </p>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

for getting data from cookies you need to use `regex` to parse the value and get the result. for example

```
document.cookie = "test1=Hello";
document.cookie = "test2=World";

var cookieValue = document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)test2\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1");
console.log(cookieValue) // World
```

[click here demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltygn32b/)

For More Details GoTo [MDN Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)